# How to calculate Lifted Index from ERA5 pressure level data?

Tags: era, python

I have taken a thunderstorm case where I need to calculate indices but I am not getting any code related stability indices in Python language, the code is available in GRADS, NCL for me it's difficult to understand. I used MetPy code but they are not calculated LI, KI, and other indices...Thanks in advance 
Below code is wrong that I know I used the formula but tell me the correct way.

```
nc1=Dataset('pl_120415.nc')
lat1=np.array(nc1.variables['latitude'])
lon1= np.array(nc1.variables['longitude'])
lev= np.array(nc1.variables['level'])
time= nc1.variables['time']
r= nc1.variables['r'][:,:,25:28,20:25]
t= nc1.variables['t']
u= nc1.variables['u'][:,:,25:28,20:25]
v= nc1.variables['v'][:]
w= nc1.variables['w']

t_500= nc1.variables['t'][:,21,:,:] ### domain Air Temperture  at 500 Pressure_level
tp_500= nc1.variables['t'][:,21,25:28,20:25] ## at specfific location temperature (parcel temperture)

li=np.subtract(t_500,tp_500,dtype=np.float32)

print("LI",li)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackexchange. Some may argue that this is off-topic here. I'd say it is on topic, but you'll need to be a lot clearer in explaining exactly what you're trying to do, and what you don't understand. "I need to calculate indices" doesn't tell me very much! What indices?

Comment: @SemidiurnalSimon thanks fo reply. Can you open this link https://weather.cod.edu/sirvatka/si.html . You may understand my query.

Answer (score 2):

Metpy 1.0 has a [lifted_index](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.lifted_index.html) function, which requires a profile temperature parameter, which in turn can be calculated using the [parcel_profile](https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.calc.parcel_profile.html) function. That requires having the dew point temperature, which you would either have to have directly, or calculate from another moisture content variable. I'm not sure what your `r` variable is, so I'm not sure whether that could help you with such a calculation. Also, rather than using numpy arrays, using [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/) for working with netcdf input variables tends to be easier and more efficient.

Comment: It is worth noting, using the lifted index function expects a 1D array. In other words, OP will have to loop through all of the times and all of the horizontal gridpoints.